# Azure Build.SourceVersionMessage returns Null on pipeline task level

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure pipeline I use Build.SourceVersionMessage variable to get last commit message. Based on that I want to decide if to build docker image or not (if commit message contains 'BUILD-DOCKER' then build docker image):

```
  ...
- task: Docker@0
  condition: and(succeeded(), contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'BUILD-DOCKER'))
  ...
```

Problem is that during pipeline execution commit message is a null:

```
Evaluating: and(succeeded(), contains(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'BUILD-DOCKER'))
Expanded: and(True, contains(Null, 'BUILD-DOCKER'))
Result: False
```

Any idea why is it null?

Additionally e.g. variable `Build.SourceBranch` is resolved properly

Comment: Do you use Git or TFVC? if git - Azure Repos? GitHub?

Comment: Git - Azure Repo

Comment: In my side, it workes perfectly :/ can you check if it null also in other pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not do anything wrong. Just, apologize to say, this is the issue which caused by us.

Because of some **design** reason which based considering on **security**, this variable was deleted from system by us. Our team has prepared the fixed code(revoke this deletion) and the PR is in progress.

The deployment procedure will be released as soon as possible. After the released finished, this variable will be shortly injected into the environment again.

Check this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/857818/cannot-read-buildsourceversionmessage-when-check-i.html) to get the in time prompt by our engineer.

---

You can use below script to check the **available variables** in system we are still providing:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'env | sort'
```

Please choose one from its result to set as in condition as a temporary work around which would not affect your build process.

Comment: I know you guys work super hard on all of this. Thanks so much and have a happy new year.

Comment: @Bon Appreciate for this, your understanding is so warm. Happy 2020!

Comment: We are now in 2023 and this variable is still null. Too bad there is not a deprecation message displayed instead to find this info on StackOverflow (deprecation message or [something in the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables)?)